# How to get element inside div, inside another html and inside another div?

Tags: javascript, html

In "first.html", I load a page inside div using Javascript.

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="lot"><a href="#" onclick="load_page()">Next</a></div>
</div>

<script>
function load_page()
{
  document.getElementById("lot").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="next.html"></object>';
}
</script>
```

Both "first.html" and "next.html" have a div called "banner". I don't want to show "banner" in "next.html". So I add the following lines in "next.html".

```
<script>
document.getElementById('banner').style.display = "none";
</script>
```

The weird thing is the banner in "first.html" disappears but not the one in "next.html".

So one way I think to get away with it is if I could reference like this.

```
"first.html" --> "lot" --> "next.html" --> "banner"
```

Then try to make it disappear.

I also try this in "next.html", but not working.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('lot').getElementById('banner').style.display = "none";
</script>
```

Thanks for the hint.

Solution: When I use iframe, it seems to work. The banner in "next.html" is clearly recognized instead of mixing with the one in "first.html".

Comment: Sounds like this could be avoided with unique IDs

Comment: `<object type="text/html" data="next.html"</object>` has a typo. The first `object` is not being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simple solution is to use different ID's for the different banners. Something like
    id="innerBanner" and id="outerBanner"

Iframe syntax:

```
<iframe src="URL" width="xxx" height="xxx"></iframe>
```

Comment: @Boyan I think user180574 is trying to embed a page's code in another page, sort of like an iframe. I don't think a hyperlink is quite the solution.

Comment: I am trying iframe now to see if it helps or not.

Comment: Cool. Just beware that some people consider iframes "tacky" if not formatted nicely. 
I added iframe syntax to my answer.

Comment: Be sure to mark the answer that helped you as the answer using the green check mark.

Comment: Although it works, it is not as ideal as I expect. Originally I have link inside div to click and be replaced with new page. But you can't put link inside iframe. But thanks indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from the folowing line :

```
document.getElementById("lot").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="next.html">  </object>'\
```

Mabye you can do the same thing with a simple hyperlink:

```
<a href="next.html">Next</a>
```

Than there is no chance, after you write the style in next.html, that it will change something in the previous page's html